# Is it more correct to say uncouple or decouple?

Tags: antonyms

Which is the correct antonym of the verb "couple"?

Comment: Have you done any research? Please show it if so, and explain why the results did not answer your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AFAIK in Engineering ...

1. ***uncouple*** is used on physical couplings. Like a train coupling (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Railway_coupling). To physically detach.
2. ***decouple*** is used on conceptual and interaction couplings, to allow mutual independence in existence and operation. For example

   - decouple the power supply fluctuation from interacting with the amplifier output.
   - decouple the correlative interaction between number of active users and the negative feedback about the content of web pages, by providing sufficient resources to serve web pages.
   - athletes seek to decouple their motivation to continue a race, from the tiredness of their body and limbs.

---

[uncouple](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/uncouple) (ʌnˈkʌpəl)

vb

1. to disconnect or unfasten or become disconnected or unfastened
2. (tr) to set loose; release

*Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridged, 12th Edition 2014 © HarperCollins Publishers 1991, 1994, 1998, 2000, 2003, 2006, 2007, 2009, 2011, 2014*

---

[de·cou·ple](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/decouple)  (dē-kŭp′əl)

tr.v. de·cou·pled, de·cou·pling, de·cou·ples

1. *Electronics* To reduce or eliminate the coupling of (one circuit or part to another).
2. *Physics* To decrease or eliminate airborne shock waves from (an explosion) by having it take place underground.
3. To separate or detach: "Bipeds have a potential advantage over quadrupeds in decoupling their breathing from their locomotion" (Craig Stanford).

de·cou′pler n.

*American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition. Copyright © 2011 by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company. Published by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company. All rights reserved.*

Answer (score 1):

I can't add any further dictionary references, @BlessedGeek seems to have that sorted. I can however answer the question by showing which word is used more often:

[image: Uncouple Vs. Decouple]

As you can see, *decouple* has risen significantly in the past few decades, possibly down to American influence on British language.

Comment: I am not sure that has anything to do with American influence. Decoupling is used in Electronics and a field of Physics regarding airborne explosions. Both areas will certainly have been discussed a lot more since the 1940s. As such, I don't think the ngrams are of much help in this case.

Comment: Frequency of use is not a good indicator here, since the two words are normally used in different contexts, and the computer-related use of "decouple" is obviously gaining of late over the mechanism-related use of "uncouple".